# How to sync specific folders in Google Drive for Desktop?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-file-stream, google-backup-and-sync

**Please note:**
I am not talking about Google's deprecated "Backup and Sync" application nor "Google Drive File Stream". This question pertains to Google's new [Drive for Desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124?visit_id=637666357792957754-4023606&rd=1).

How do I only sync specific folders? On the settings page it only allows me to select between Streaming and Mirroring.
[image: Drive for Desktop preferences screen]

Google claims that syncing specific folders is possible in Drive for Desktop but the feature seems to be missing: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7638428
[image: Drive for Desktop features list]